# Service Contract Namespace : Why

Tags: wcf

Bit confused with specifying a namespace for the service contract. Can understand with respect to a normal class,

My understanding about namespace

In normal OOPs model, say Employee class is part of Microsoft name space as well as Google name space. But since we  may add reference to Google as well as Microsoft assembly in our project; hence to differentiate Employee's we have namespace, since when we say

`Employee emp = new Employee()`... compiler really doesn't really know which employee we are referring to?

Similarly, with respect to web service how does it matter? May I request an explicit example to explain the case please? For example

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace="Company.Matching.Algo")]
```

Answer (score 39, accepted):

It's used - just like regular .NET namespaces - to keep things apart.

Having a namespace helps when you have multiple services that might end up all having similar methods exposed. With a namespace, they can all have a method called `GetVersion` or something, and the WSDL document will be able to keep them apart based on their namespace.

Also, namespaces are often used for **versioning**, so your first WCF service might have a service namespace of  `http://yourcompany.com/MyService/2011/08` and have five methods. If you later on introduce a v2 of your service, which might have 10 methods, and you put it into a separate namespace of `http://yourcompany.com/MyService/2011/12` then you can keep those things separate - and an "old" client can still call the "old" service with (`/2011/08`) and use its method, while new clients can already call the new service with more capabilities.

Comment: Then why don't use v1, v2 instead of 2011/08 and 2011/12?

Comment: @inTagger: if you prefer using version numbers - that's fine, too! It just seems to be a common practice to include year/month in contract namespaces in the WCF world - but there's no rule that you have to!

Comment: hmm is there any way to configure this per environment more easily?  Lets say you deploy your web service to your QA or Dev server from your PC (localhost)..  You don't want people having to go into the service contract every time changing this.  e.g. http://myCompany.qaserver or http://mycompany.Production just as hypothetical examples (yea bad names but you get the point)

Comment: I'm wondering if you can just omit the namespace altogether if there are no existing conflicts.  But then again, for versioning do most people use it anyway at the least for that?  Trying to get a feel for how often this is really used in reality.

Comment: @CoffeeAddict: I wouldn't change the service namespace for each platform (dev, testing etc.) - I'd only change the **server URL** that I connect to.

Comment: @marc_s Thanks for the your answer, I am try to understand the work or role of the Namespace in the ServiceContract.
I have the One service which already deployed and used by the many clients and that service does not have the Namespace in the ServiceContract.
So now i have the version upgrade in my service and I add the version like this "http://tempuri.org/V2.0.0" So it means that my old client will not be able to call the my service ?\

Answer (score 10):

From [RebuildAll](http://rebuildall.umbraworks.net/2010/11/10/WCF_service_namespaces):

> A note on namespaces: namespaces ARE NOT URLS!. They might look like one, like in my examples, but there is no such subdomain as schemas actually in existence. Namespaces follow the URI format, but are not actual addresses. They can be used to identify schemas, because usually a company owns a domain name. Thus using that as the schema namespace creates something unique. And that is exactly what namespaces should be: unique.

Answer (score 4):

The namespace is important for serializing and deserializing objects.

In your example you can have the same Employee class on the server and client, and send an Employee object from one to the other over a web service. If the namespace is different it will be null when you deserialize on the otherside.

Comment: Sorry about not being explicit... I wanted to ask about Namespace property for ServiceOperation attribute. 
[ServiceContract(Namespace="Company.Matching.Algo")]

How is it used by developers, or WCF to identify the objects? May I've some examples on that please?